# Shift lever can’t move cage to large chain ring. Shimano Ultegra 11 speed hydraulic

Tags: repair, shifter, chainring

The large lever can’t be moved more than a short distance to where it would normally start moving the cage but won’t move any farther. It doesn’t move the cage at all. Something in the shifter is preventing full movement.
Local shop replaced the cable and sprayed some cleaner and lubricant in the shifter mechanism and it will now sometimes shift, but generally doesn’t.

I can move the cage by hand over the large chain ring then the shift lever can be moved as normal and will hold the cage in the large chain ring position. Shifting down to the small ring from there works fine.
The lever usually just hits a hard stop and the cage doesn’t move at all. But again, the cage can easily be moved by hand so the problem must be in the shifter.

I’ve ordered a new shifter from the shop but it would be nice if we could fix it instead of full replacement.
Shimano Ultegra R8020 on a 2016 BMC Road Machine Two 02.

Comment: Youtube might be a good resource because there are quite a few videos where people service their shifters, does [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQOYNn4QYDs,) help:  or maybe [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-iCoVAvXug)?

Answer (score 2):

Shimano do not make internal parts available as spares to shops or consumers. The lever may be repairable at your country's distributor's warranty centre, but we generally get a complete replacement. The same is true with brake calipers, hydraulic levers, etc. If the component part is not shown on  the EV (exploded view) document, it can't be ordered from the distributor.

Internally the mechanism is small, complex enough and sprung so as to make it a "labour of love" to operate on: i.e. no fun at all.

If you want shifters that can be repaired, try Campagnolo.

Comment: Actually, my understanding is that Campy don’t make the replacement parts available anymore. They can be scavenged from damaged levers, but that requires getting your hands on one.

Comment: @WeiwenNg meh, they can still fix them at the service centre

Answer (score -1):

It sounds to me like the rear derailleur HI limit needs adjusting. The 2 small Philips head screws on your derailleur one is HI limit one is LOW limit. Adjust the HI limit by unscrewing (counter clockwise) about 1/2 turn and check the shifting. Repeat this until you can shift the chain on the big gear. Be careful and do small 1/2 turns at a time because you can go to far and throw the chain off of the cassette over the big gear and into your spokes.

Comment: That does not make sense. The rear derailleur limit screws have no bearing on limiting the travel of the front derailleur cage. Suggest editing your answer.

Comment: That's not it. The problem is with the shift lever and the bike shop thinks that something in the ratcheting mechanism is preventing the lever from moving far enough to begin pulling the cable and moving the cage. The cage does not move at all this happens. I can move the cage by hand to the large ring and then the handle will move, I assume because moving the cage pulls on the cable/ratchet mechanism and allows the handle to move. Obviously can't do this while riding so I then have to turn the pedals to move the chain onto the large ring, which is not easy since the bike is on a smart wheel-o